Join 2 tables with closest date
I have 2 tables that looks something like this:
T1
| Ordernr  | Itemnr   | Price    | Date         | Currency |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | ------------ | -------- |
| 1        | aaa      | 10       | 2024-04-15   | EUR      |
| 1        | bbb      | 20       | 2024-04-15   | EUR      |
| 1        | ccc      | 15       | 2024-04-15   | EUR      |
| 2        | aaa      | 20       | 2024-04-16   | USD      |
| 2        | bbb      | 20       | 2024-04-16   | USD      |
| 3        | aaa      | 20       | 2024-04-16   | EUR      |
| 3        | bbb      | 20       | 2024-04-16   | EUR      |

T2
| Currency | Date         | ExchangeRate
| -------- | ------------ | ------------
| EUR      | 2024-04-17   | 10,4
| USD      | 2024-04-17   | 11,0
| EUR      | 2024-04-16   | 10,3
| USD      | 2024-04-16   | 11,1
| EUR      | 2024-04-14   | 10,2
| USD      | 2024-04-14   | 11,2

As you can see in t2 there is some date that is missing, in this case 2024-04-15.
In my query I want to get full order price from t1 and multiply it with the exchange rate that matches the date and currency in t2, if date missing in t2 I want to match to closest date under.
This is what I get so far:
Select 
 t1.Ordernr, 
 t1.Date,
 Sum(t1.Price * t2.ExchangeRate) as Orderprice,
 t2.ExchangeRate

from t1 
inner join t2
  on t1.Currency = t2.Currency
  and t1.Date = t2.Date

Group by t1.Date, t1.Ordernr, t1.Price, t2.ExchangeRate

This results in following:
| Ordernr  | Date         | Orderprice   | ExchangeRate
| -------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------------
| 1        | 2024-04-15   | Null         | Null
| 2        | 2024-04-16   | 444          | 11,1
| 3        | 2024-04-16   | 412          | 10,3

But I want this result:
| Ordernr  | Date         | Orderprice   | ExchangeRate
| -------- | ------------ | ------------ | ------------
| 1        | 2024-04-15   | 459          | 10,2
| 2        | 2024-04-16   | 444          | 11,1
| 3        | 2024-04-16   | 412          | 10,3

I understand why I get null values but I don't know how to get the result I want.
Anyone here that can help me with the query?

Is it an option to fill those gaps in a first step? Would make things way easier if you could guarantee that there are no gaps.

I wonder what currency orderprice is expressed in given the mix of eur and usd

Would something like this work for you? (Just a quick idea, query is untested)
SELECT 
    t1.Ordernr, 
    t1.Date,
    SUM(t1.Price * t2.ExchangeRate) as Orderprice,
    t2.ExchangeRate
FROM 
    t1 
INNER JOIN t2
    ON 
        t1.Currency = t2.Currency
    AND 
        t2.Date = (
            SELECT 
                subt2.Date
            FROM 
                t2 AS subt2
            WHERE 
                subt2.Date >= t1.Date
            ORDER BY 
                subt2.Date ASC 
            LIMIT 1
        )
GROUP BY
    t1.Date, t1.Ordernr, t1.Price, t2.ExchangeRate


Thanks for your answer, that will work!
